Is there a clever way to implement CeilingEntry equivalent of Java TreeMap in C# SortedDictionary, in O(logn)?
You may see similar questions on this topic - like this one and this.
The main reason I want to use a SortedDictionary is to have search and insertion functionalities in O(log n) - the best case complexity of balanced binary search tree. The search use case I am interested is when key being searched for is not found i.e when we want to find item just greater or just less than the searched item (like CeilingEntry and FloorEntry in Java) - it should be doable in O(log n) since underlying data structure allows that.
The previous answers suggest some form of utilizing SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>.Keys, but the problem is that we can't perform the inbuilt BinarySearch on SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection class. The workaround proposed for this is to convert the Keys into a List and then go about using BinarySearch and finding the apt index but converting to a List will defeat the purpose as its an O(n) operation.
I had one idea of using GetEnumerator of the KeyCollection class to perform binary search on it directly, but I imagine it to be very ugly.

Is there a reason you cannot use SortedList<TKey, TValue> as detailed in the answer to the second question you linked? Its key collection is an IList<TKey>.

You can't usefully implement binary search with an enumerator anyway, you need random access otherwise the time complexity degrades to O(n) again.

@ZdeněkJelínek Insertion into a SortedList<TKey, TValue> is an O(n) operation so it cannot be replaced by SortedDictionary. Also, if I wanted to use SortedList just for the search, then also, creating SortedList from Dictionary keys will lead to O(n)

Could you specify your requirements regarding operations and their complexities in your question? There is nothing about insertion complexity being important at this point.

@ShubhamChaudhary the question is unclear because it depends on people knowing how some Java class behaves and assumptions about the actual behavior of classes. O(N) notation is misleading in real life, where CPU caching and data locality can result in significant performance differences - even orders of magnitude better or worse. A supposedly O(N) operation that uses SIMD operations to work on 4 cached values at a time is a lot faster than following pointers to main RAM in O(logN). The same holds for dumb loops over cached values

So what's the actual question? Fast negative searches? Fast merging? Something else that can be solved with more modern data structures like dataframes or Arrow? What about parallel processing? There are a lot of third-party libraries meant for large datasets, which aim for good real-life performance and parallelism instead of algorithmic complexity

Code in this answer was tested with .NET 8. It will require adjustments to work with .NET 6 or .NET Framework due to them missing IMinMaxValue<TSelf> (and interface statics in general).
The behavior you want can be achieved by using SortedSet<T> which allows access to a subset using GetViewBetween which returns a view in SortedSet<T> shape that has Min and Max properties:
public static T? CeilingEntry<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T value) where T : IMinMaxValue<T>
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(value, T.MaxValue).Min;
}

public static T? FloorEntry<T>(this SortedSet<T> set, T value) where T : IMinMaxValue<T>
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(T.MinValue, value).Max;
}

Example usage:
var set = new SortedSet<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 5: {set.FloorEntry(5)}"); // 4
Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 6: {set.FloorEntry(6)}"); // 6
Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 7: {set.FloorEntry(7)}"); // 6

Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 5: {set.CeilingEntry(5)}"); // 6
Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 6: {set.CeilingEntry(6)}"); // 6
Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 7: {set.CeilingEntry(7)}"); // 8

SortedSet<T> performance characteristics are not documented, but since the implementation is backed by a red-black tree the operation complexities are O(log n) for insertion and search (which is both view creation as well as Min/Max access).
If a dictionary-like behavior is intended, this can be achieved by either storing a separate Dictionary<TKey, TValue> or using a key-value struct where only the key is part of the comparison, e.g.:
public readonly struct Entry<TKey, TValue> : IEquatable<Entry<TKey, TValue>>, IComparable<Entry<TKey, TValue>>
    where TKey : IMinMaxValue<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>, IComparable<TKey>
{
    public TKey Key { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }

    public Entry(TKey key, TValue value) => (Key, Value) = (key, value);

    // Only reflect Key in comparisons
    public bool Equals(Entry<TKey, TValue> other) => Key.Equals(other.Key);
    public int CompareTo(Entry<TKey, TValue> other) => Key.CompareTo(other.Key);

    public override string ToString() => $$"""{ Key = {{Key}}, Value = {{Value}} }""";
}

public static Entry<TKey, TValue>? CeilingEntry<TKey, TValue>(this SortedSet<Entry<TKey, TValue>> set, TKey key)
    where TKey : IMinMaxValue<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>, IComparable<TKey>
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(new(key, default!), new(TKey.MaxValue, default!)).Min;
}

public static Entry<TKey, TValue>? FloorEntry<TKey, TValue>(this SortedSet<Entry<TKey, TValue>> set, TKey key)
    where TKey : IMinMaxValue<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>, IComparable<TKey>
{
    return set.GetViewBetween(new(TKey.MinValue, default!), new(key, default!)).Max;
}

Note that there's a ton of generics. If you restrict the key to e.g. int, the code will be a bit simpler.
Usage:
var complexSet = new SortedSet<Entry<int, string>> { new(2, "two"), new(4, "four"), new(6, "six"), new(8, "eight"), new(10, "ten") };

Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 5: {complexSet.FloorEntry(5)}"); // { Key = 4, Value = four }
Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 6: {complexSet.FloorEntry(6)}"); // { Key = 6, Value = six }
Console.WriteLine($"Floor entry for 7: {complexSet.FloorEntry(7)}"); // { Key = 6, Value = six }

Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 5: {complexSet.CeilingEntry(5)}"); // { Key = 6, Value = six }
Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 6: {complexSet.CeilingEntry(6)}"); // { Key = 6, Value = six }
Console.WriteLine($"Ceiling entry for 7: {complexSet.CeilingEntry(7)}"); // { Key = 8, Value = eight }

I'm not entirely sure about perf of this (what gets JIT-devirtualized, if it does not end up with too many generics, copying of stack data, etc.). I'd wrap it into a separate type to avoid exposing the default! ugliness and have an API that works with keys and values just like Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.
If searching for exact value is needed, the SortedSet<T> has TryGetValue that should do the trick, since Contains won't be very useful in this case.
